# Выборка из нескольких колонок

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица к примеру:

```
| Last_Name | First_Name |  
+-----------+------------+  
| Куприй    | Анатолий   |
```

Запрос :

```
declare
    @Name nvarchar(200) = 'Куприй Анатолий'
BEGIN
    select * from dbo.Clients
    where 
     (Last_Name like '%' +@Name+ '%') 
     or 
     (First_Name like '%' +@name+ '%')  
END
```

Если в параметре написать фамилии + имя запрос не работает.
Как сделать чтобы с помощью одного параметра запрос искал из разных колонок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае самое простое наверно так:

```
declare
    @Name nvarchar(200) = 'Куприй Анатолий'
BEGIN
    select * from dbo.Clients
    where 
     (Last_Name + ' ' + First_Name like '%' +@Name+ '%') 
     or 
     (First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name like '%' +@name+ '%')  
END
```

надо только подумать, как вам быть с двойными пробелами и прочим?

Comment: интересный способ, я бы наверно делал через `union`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Name nvarchar(200) = 'Куприй Анатолий'
    select * from dbo.Clients
    where 
     @Name=ltrim(rtrim(Last_Name)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(First_Name))
     or 
     @Name=ltrim(rtrim(first_Name)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(last_Name))
```